# Htaccess rule for generating pretty url for languages

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling here with an htaccess rewrite rule.

I have a website that is using **Wordpress** and **WPML** language plugin.

I have three languages and url structure is as follows: www.sitename.**com** and all languages are structured like this: www.sitename.**com/fr**, www.sitename.**com/es** and so on.

Now, I have another alias domain, www.sitename.**es** that I would like to direct to sitename.**com/es** and keep my pretty permalink **sitename.es/pagename** that would be in old format sitename.**com/es/pagename**

Contacted my hosting partner and they recommended htaccess rule for that. But I have no experience with that and thats why I am here.

Currently **.es** alias domain is directing to .com homepage.

How can I do it?

Comment: WPML must be able to do this without configure your .htaccess. If your .es is redirected to your .com, I think it's more a problem of dns. Contact your hosting partner

Comment: WPML is able to do it, but only full on, for every language. Current situation demands only one language being like that.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, configure your .htaccess like this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sitename.com/es [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This seems to not work. As I have .es domain .com alias then it autodirect to .com site and no url rewriting is working.

Comment: Your .es is an alias or a real domain ? If it's a real domain, contact your hosting partner and ask them to erase a potential configuration.